# Writing to csv has empty rows

Tags: python, csv

I have this script:

```
import csv
import unicodedata

with open('output.csv', 'a', encoding='cp1252') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)

    with open('input.csv', 'r', encoding='cp1252') as csvfile:
        for row in csv.reader(csvfile):
            name_array = u''.join([c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', row[0].lower()) if (c.isalnum() or c.isspace()) if not unicodedata.combining(c)]).split()
            writer.writerow(name_array)
```

which would create a name breakdown from a csv list of names. It works fine but the output has empty rows between successful name breakdowns.

Sample `input.csv`:

```
"Lastname, Firstname Secondname"
"Lastname1 Lastname2, Firstname1"
```

Sample `output.csv`:

```
lastname,firstname,secondname
   ##### empty row ####
lastname1,lastname2,firstname1
```

How do I remove the empty row?

Comment: You’re using `as csvfile` twice; try changing that to at least reduce confusion potential? The first one could be `outputcsvfile` and the second `inputcsvfile`.

Comment: Maybe you should check if `name_array = u''.join([c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', row[0].lower()) if (c.isalnum() or c.isspace()) if not unicodedata.combining(c)]).split()` is returning something you don’t want to write to your CSV? Try printing `name_array`? Then add some defensive code if `name_array` is empty then not write to the CSV?

Comment: Plus, with Python 3 you don’t need the u in `u’’`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `csv.writer`, specify a keyword argument for `lineterminator='\n'`, which should eliminate the extra empty line.